# Referencing `this` in inline event handlers

Tags: javascript, html

I want to be able to pass 'this' in a javascript 'mouseover'. I basically want to get the href from a link (that is unique) and pass it to every download button. But I get the error message:

> undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.getElementsByClassName('downLoad_link')[0].href = x)

Quite new to this so I hope anyone could help me! :)

Here is my code:

```
<a onmouseover="this.getElementsByClassName('downLoad_link')[0].href = 'www.example.com'" href="" class="downLoad_link" download>
    <button class="download">Download</button>
</a>
```

**EDIT:**

*'www.example.com'* will be replaced by a variable when I get to fix this issue!

Okay so my new code is this:

**Javascript:**

```
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
       var x = this.getElementsByClassName('getDownloadLink')[0].href; //this is not working!
    </script>
```

**HTML:**

```
<a onmouseover="this.getElementsByClassName('downLoad_link')[0].href = x" href="" class="downLoad_link" download>Download</a>
```

Comment: Why can't you have a dedicated handler for this?

Comment: Why do you need `this` there? Looks like It'd work without `this`, or you could use `this.href = '...'`.

Comment: `this` refers to `a`. Why do you want to call `getElementsByClassName` on an `a` tag?

Comment: @31piy — To get elements which are members of a particular class that are inside the link.

Comment: The error is because `getElementsByClassName('downLoad_link')` returns an _empty_ [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection), so you are accessing an element that's not there (`undefined`). From the question it seems you are looking to set the `href`  attribute on the `mouseover` event, for which you could simply do `this.href = 'www.example.com'`, as `this` already refers to the `a` element itself. What you are currently doing is looking for an element with `downLoad_link` _inside_ that element, which is most likely not what you intended.

Comment: @Kobi it is supposed to be unique, when I used to use jQuery, I had an 'this' handler. It is supposed to give an unique value based on the link I am referring to. I'll refer to a variable instead of 'www.example.com'

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. You **cannot** have a `<button>` inside an `<a>`.

Comment: I breaks UI conventions to use links like buttons, it's just as bad to use buttons like links. The are intended to have different behaviours.

Comment: Hey! I have updated the question, again, thank you so much for looking into it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just use `this` not `this.getElementsByClassName('downLoad_link')[0]`

```html
<a onmouseover="this.href = 'www.example.com'" href="" class="downLoad_link" download>
  <button class="download">
    Download
    </button>
</a>
```

Comment: @Ritacodes Make sure to accept the answer (by clicking the "tick" icon) if it resolved your issue.

Comment: It worked! But now look at my edited question, I tried referring to it but it won't work

Comment: @Ritacodes,`var x = document.getElementsByClassName('getDownloadLink')[0].href;`

Comment: But that gets only the first link and gives it to the value of all the links in the 'get posts' loop

Comment: @Ritacodes,suggest you post a complete question and state what you want and what you have tried

Answer (score 1):

I think this will answer your second question that you have.

```js
var x = document.getElementById('getDownloadLink').href; //this is not working!
```

```html
<a onmouseover="alert(x)" href="random" id="getDownloadLink">Download</a>
```

Here the value of the href gets put in the variable x. As an example I now changed the onmouseover as alert(x).